# How can we be sure that all call_rcu() callbacks are invoked/completed in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, rcu

I have a kmem_cache which contains RCU-protected data.

I also use call_rcu() after updating the RCU-protected pointers to free the elements in further.

Before destroying the cache i have to make sure that all slabs are freed.

The documentation says that both synchronize_rcu() and call_rcu()'s callbacks wait for an end of the current grace period. So there's no guarantee that once the synchronize_rcu() returns all call_rcu()'s callbacks are completed and particularly freed the slabs. Neither i haven't found a guarantee that all call_rcu() callbacks are invoked synchronously in a FIFO manner which could allow us to use one more call_rcu() for the destroying the cache.

**So, how can i make sure that all RCU-protected data are freed before destroying the cache?**

P.S. In my case with x86-64 Linux kernel the synchronize_rcu() waits until all call_rcu()'s callbacks are completed and it somehow works, but it seems like undefined behaviour in terms of documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the rcu_barrier() function.

From the https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/rcubarrier.txt:

> Unloading Modules That Use call_rcu()
>
> But what if p_callback is defined in an unloadable module?
>
> If we unload the module while some RCU callbacks are pending, the CPUs
> executing these callbacks are going to be severely disappointed when
> they are later invoked, as fancifully depicted at
> http://lwn.net/images/ns/kernel/rcu-drop.jpg.
>
> We could try placing a synchronize_rcu() in the module-exit code path,
> but this is not sufficient. Although synchronize_rcu() does wait for a
> grace period to elapse, it does not wait for the callbacks to
> complete.
>
> One might be tempted to try several back-to-back synchronize_rcu()
> calls, but this is still not guaranteed to work. If there is a very
> heavy RCU-callback load, then some of the callbacks might be deferred
> in order to allow other processing to proceed. Such deferral is
> required in realtime kernels in order to avoid excessive scheduling
> latencies.
>
> rcu_barrier()
>
> We instead need the rcu_barrier() primitive.  Rather than waiting for
> a grace period to elapse, rcu_barrier() waits for all outstanding RCU
> callbacks to complete.  Please note that rcu_barrier() does -not-
> imply synchronize_rcu(), in particular, if there are no RCU callbacks
> queued anywhere, rcu_barrier() is within its rights to return
> immediately, without waiting for a grace period to elapse.
>
> Pseudo-code using rcu_barrier() is as follows:
>
> 1. Prevent any new RCU callbacks from being posted.
> 2. Execute rcu_barrier().
> 3. Allow the module to be unloaded.